# Bounding Player to path Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Lets say I have a path, could be a line or a curve in Unity and I wanted to allow my player to snap to that path and move along it how would I achieve this. This would look like either a cover system or something similar to how ledges work in Sly Cooper.

Answer (score 0):

While if you want your player's movement to follow a path, there is a technique called `WayPoint`, which is simply using the build-in navigation system in Unity. There exist so many articles that teaching you how to manually build such a Way Point System, and at the same time, you can get a SimpleWayPoint module from the online assets store.
But if your player is controlled by user, which means the user can control it's movement, let's say pressing 'W' button meaning moving forward while pressing 'S' button meaning moving backwards, and the leftwards and rightwards movement are constrained by the path you defined, unfortunately I didn't find any mature technology which allows you realize this constrains.
However, in the project I accomplished several months ago, I manually handle the coordinates successfully, since I create a city whose streets strictly observe horizontal and vertical grid lines, I can easily controls the target gameobject's `X and Y coordinates`, by either **using the build-in freeze coordinates API** or **manually reseting the axis values over and over again in the Update()** method. So maybe you could using the Update() method to constrain the targets' coordinates by dynamically calculating it's coordinates using the functions representing the path, but I can imagine how complex it would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

1. Mark the position from where you want your player NOT to move forward/cross the line.
2. In your script, mention the position.

LOGIC

if, player position > position marked
then stop the movement,

SYNTAX

```
private void update(){
    if(transform.position.x < -10){
    transform.position = new Vector3(-10, transform.position.y, transform.position.z); // Here you can either use `Vector3` or `Vector2`  according to your game
    }
}
```

Comment: So I think this solves the case of a simple line on axis but doesn't answer for anything more complex, like curves or 3d paths

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a navmeshagent, which will be enabled as soon the player would like to use this "auto movement". In your code you can set the destination and in your scene you can create a navmesh, which can be whatever shape you like